# Telerik ASP.NET controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I looked at the Telerik ASP.NET controls and I like them. But they're REALLY expensive at $1000 odd for a single developer, especially one starting out on a new business idea. Lots of people here use Telerik so I thought I will ask... Anyone aware of a discount coupon or similar so that I can purchase these controls at a more reasonable price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER - I work at Telerik :)

I suggest you send an email to sales@telerik.com. I am sure you would be able to arrange some discount in exchange of a testimonial or case study.

Answer (score 1):

They used to give them out for free at one point to StackOverflow users who reached 10,000 reputation. Maybe if you earn 10K rep and ask them nicely they'll do the same for you - or at least give you a discount. :)

Here's the Meta thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/thanks-to-both-stackoverflow-and-telerik-for-the-awesome-promotion